# ERROR: Error converting text to date; Error while executing the query

Tags: mysql, amazon-redshift, tableau-api, tableau-desktop

I have connected Amazon Redshift as a live connection to Tableau Desktop. Table I am connecting has a date field in the format '2021-04-12 11:18:05' and also several rows have '0'. Whenever I drag this file in Tableau to form a table, I am getting the following error:

`ERROR: Error converting text to date; Error while executing the query`.

I tried converting it to string and exact date but still, the error persists. I also wrote the calculated field as follows still the error persists:

```
 if [My Date Field]= '0'  then null
else DATE(LEFT([My Date Field],10)) end
```

Could you please suggest what can be done (I cannot use DATEPARSE because it is a live connection)?

Comment: What is the data type of the field in Redshift?

Comment: It is str type there

Comment: After you connect to Redshift and drag your table to the canvas, what data type does Tableau Desktop assign to this field?